# htaccess - remove .php extension from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I tried a lot of code to remove `.php` from url
for example - `ht.abuena.net/presto.php` -> `ht.abuena.net/presto`
and vice versa - internally

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

nothing works - the url stays unchanged
page is reloading by right clicking on the button `Reload` and choosing - `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` - so I hope the cache is cleared

live example here - [here](https://ht.abuena.net/presto.php)

Comment: Why would the URL change? You don't do any redirection, only a rewrite. And why _should_ it even change? The whole point is that you can have an URL like `https://example.com/stuff` internally served by `/stuff.php` (without the client even seeing any `.php` at all). I think you have it the wrong way round - just don't send people to `/presto.php` at all, link them to `/presto` instead...

Comment: @CherryDT - what if I have a folder named `presto` also ?

Comment: That would be a confusing semantical structure...

Comment: @CherryDT - ok suppose there is no such a folder. Are you sure that a link without file extension will always go to that file ? I think this is not a default, or regular browser's behaviour

Comment: No it's not default but it's what your `.htaccess` achieves that you showed above... Maybe I am misunderstanding the point here. I was thinking you want nice URLs without `.php`, so what you'd do is use the `.htaccess` setup that you posted above so that `/abc` will internally reach `/abc.php`. Anything else didn't make much sense to me. If that's not the case, can you explain better what you want to achieve here then, and why?

Comment: @CherryDT - yes, the goal is nice url. I'm just not sure in writing a link without a file extension, seems a tricky solution

Comment: @CherryDT - `presto` is nice url, `presto.php` is not. You suggest me to write just `presto` instead of `presto.php`. And that what I'm suspicious about - regarding a valid browser's interpretation

Comment: The browser doesn't care about it. It just sends the URL to your server. It matters what your server does with that URL and what response it returns. That's where your `.htaccess` file comes in - it rewrites `/presto` to `/presto.php` on the server side (the browser doesn't know about that), causing the `/presto` response to be served by your `presto.php` file. All the browser will see is that when it sends `/presto` to your server, the server responds with some HTML. (That this HTML is actually generated by `presto.php` is something that happens behind the curtain on the server side)

Comment: ah, ok, that's so logical. And is it then tricky for the server? How the server know I need `presto.php`? Having `presto.css`, or `presto.js` is so normal, isnt it ?

Comment: see my comment above pls

Comment: How it knows: Because of the `.htaccess` file that you showed above - what it does is, it checks if some file named `<filename from URL>.php` exists (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`), and if yes, it rewrites the URL by appending `.php` before further processing (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]`).

Comment: but your suggestion is to avoid `htaccess` file totally. Am I right ?

Comment: No. My suggestion is to use the file that you showed, which should work fine as-is. You were saying you expected `/presto.php` to be _redirected_ to `/presto` though, which is not what the file does, but it's also normally not necessary, because you wouldn't even use a `/presto.php` URL at all... It could be added, but since you said your real goal was just to support nice URLs without `.php`, I figured it's not even needed and the issue was just that you expected something specific to happen that didn't happen while in fact the `.htaccess` file still did fulfill the original nice-URL goal

Comment: I see, finally, thanks a lot and lot for your efforts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
##using THE_REQUEST variable for condition check.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php/?\s [NC]
##Performing external redirect here.
RewriteRule ^  %1? [R=301,L]

##Performing rewrite for non-existing pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks, url is rewriten but I'm getting error `404 - Not Found`

Comment: @qadenza, could you please do let me know where is your htaccess present and where is your php file?

Comment: live address - https://ht.abuena.net/presto.php. htaccess file is in root and presto.php also

Comment: @qadenza, could you please try edited rules once? Please make sure to clear cache before testing your urls.

Comment: the same result. Pls try yourself on the given address

Comment: @qadenza, somehow that link is not working so I couldn't test. I have made a minor change please try that out and let's see how it goes.

Comment: now the page is there but there is no any redirection - `.php` extension is there. Why you can't see my page, could you give me a PrintScreen, pls

Comment: @qadenza, please try my edited rules now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: now redirection works, but `error 404 Not Found` - again

Comment: @qadenza, try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` once and test it once?

Comment: but I didn't write that lines of code. Your comment says - `for non-existing pages` - and my page is existing. Anyway, I now write all of your code - and it works fine. Maybe it would be better if you could write your first version. Sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: @qadenza, no no you should have full htaccess like I showed, then only it will work 

Comment: @qadenza, do after redirection 301 it looks redirects but if we don't write this internal rewrite rule then it's not going to find the actual file in backend. Please use all lines on my current code and then try 

Answer (score 1):

In my case if the project is core PHP one, I use the below lines in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. There is no redirection. And yes - it's a pure php site

Comment: Check in your server's httpd.conf file for AllowOverride entry. It should be AllowOverride All

Comment: I'm trying to find that file on server - in cpanel file manager - without success

Comment: @qadenza "There is no redirection." - That's correct. There shouldn't be a redirection under normal circumstances. You would only implement a redirect (which would be an additional rule) if the old URL had been indexed by search engines or linked to by external third parties. You should have already changed all your internal links (in your HTML source) to reference the extensionless URL - so under normal usage, no redirect is necessary.

Comment: @MrWhite - so if I write just `presto` instead of `presto.php` - without any `htaccess` file - is that what you mean ?

Comment: @qadenza Well, not quite. You "write just `presto`", but you obviously need to use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the request from `presto` to `presto.php` (which is what the above rule is doing). This is called URL-rewriting. Otherwise you'll simply get a 404, since `presto` does not map to a file and Apache does not know what to do with it.

Comment: ok, I see, thanks a lot. Have you pls any good resource to learn and understand all the confusing stuff about `htaccess`

Comment: @qadenza Not really, sorry. The Apache docs are my go-to, but they are rather lacking in examples. What you are dealing with here is mod_rewrite - which is just one of many Apache modules. It is one of the more complex (and powerful) Apache modules. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/

Comment: @MrWhite - seems to me that things are mistically hidden. So much titles on web - without a real explanation. Anyway, thanks again, knowing what is unknown - is a kind of knowing